# Which methods are called by java debugger when debugging collections?

Tags: java, debugging, junit, deque

Recently I've come into issue that when debugging my deque implementation the size is returned correctly, mainly because it's obvious that `size()` is called to determine it, while its last item is returned as null even if it isn't null. How come? Which function does debugger call to determine the value of element?

Note: the following tests do pass without throwing exceptions.

[image]

[Deque implementation](https://gist.github.com/Dragas/baa5ef02d2222de121b970757f9afded)

[JUnit tests](https://gist.github.com/Dragas/a329a172a4dbfc0f1e7190552e530dd7)

Comment: "How come?" Because your code is broken. If you post it in the question (as *text*, not an image or a link), you might get more help.

Comment: By the way, calling your variables the same name as their type (e.g. `T T` in `public boolean offerFirst(T T)`) is legal but not a very good idea, as it's confusing (to a reader) which `T` you mean in any given context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods called by java debugger are `size()` to determine data structure's size while `toArray()` is called to determine structure's content.

By the way, the mistake was at line 365, where instead of comparing index to size I compared array's size (`index+1`) to its capacity.